How do I fix the issue of the gmail app on mobile opening a mailto link with an empty recipient, despite the recipient being in the link?
I'm having this issue where i'm setting up a button in my website with the link
mailto:someone@example.com
that works perfectly on desktop (even if I set the subject and content they prefill as expected), but on my phone it opens the gmail app without the recipient set (subject and content prefill correctly)
